# ElasticSearch: Can I write query-time plugin like in Solr?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Solr, I was able to write some query-time plugin to do some kind of query rewriting (generating sub queries and so on) but in ElasticSearch I can't find anything similar here. For example, in Solr I created a plugin which creates a OR sub query with low multiplicative boosting to the original query (by default the original query is AND). The point here is to show AND results first followed by OR results since running OR query alone doesn't guarantee results with all query word show up first.

Here is an example:

- Let's say I have a query 'A B C'
- This plugin will be converting this query into the following:

  - AND(A,B,C) + OR(A,B,C)*0.000001

I achieved this by writing a simple runtime plugin in Solr but no idea how to do this in ElasticSearch.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write elasticsearch plugins as well and hook into one of its many extension points, for instance plug in your own custom query. Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve please?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add one example to my question. Please let me know if it is specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into boosting you don't need to write a plugin, just play around with the query DSL (bool query with should clauses) or the [function_score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for more advanced usecases. If that's not enough you can always write your own query through a plugin, but that's for even more advanced usecases, you usually don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I think what I need is more advanced use cases so any pointer/example around the plugin would be appreciated!

Comment: Given what you describe, I tend to think you don't need to write a plugin and your own query, I encourage you to read more about the function_score query and what you can do with it. On the other hand, if you add more details to your question (e.g. examples) I can try and help with examples on my answer too.

Comment: I added a bit more detail but at the same time I will read more about function_score query. Please see if this can be done by function_score or I need to write a plugin. Thanks a lot!